# Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid show subset of properties

Tags: c#, wpf, propertygrid

I am using a propertygrid of an extension for wpf (Extended WPF Toolkit Community Edition), and in my application (runtime) as I select an item (the application is like an interface designer), like a Label (System.Windows.Controls.Label) it shows me all its properties. I want to show a subset of properties, like font size and color, for example.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> By default the propertyGrid will autogenerate all the properties for a
>   given object. You can override this behavior by setting the
>   AutoGenerateProperties property to False, and then provide a
>   collection of PropertyDefinitions of the properties you would like to
>   show.

```
<xctk:PropertyGrid x:Name="_propertyGrid" Width="450" Margin="10"
  AutoGenerateProperties="False">
  <!-- Only the following properties will be displayed in the PropertyGrid-->
      <xctk:PropertyGrid.PropertyDefinitions>
        <xctk:PropertyDefinition Name="FontSize" />
        <xctk:PropertyDefinition Name="FontFamily" />
        <xctk:PropertyDefinition Name="Foreground" />            
      </xctk:PropertyGrid.PropertyDefinitions>
</xctk:PropertyGrid>
```

Comment: thanks, but i need the actual properties of System.Windows.Controls.Label, how do i get to them?

Comment: All Label properties are available on MSDN... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.label.aspx